# How to stop wordpress from injecting hard-coded style into image attachments with captions

Tags: functions, attachments, css

Every time I add a caption to a wordpress image, wordpress decides its going to insert a hard coded style="" into the attachment html which breaks my sidebar.

[image]

All images without captions are inserted, perfectly normally like this (which doesn't break the theme)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the `img_caption_shortcode_width` filter, within the [`img_caption_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/img_caption_shortcode/):

```
/**
 * Filters the width of an image's caption.
 *
 * By default, the caption is 10 pixels greater than the width of the image,
 * to prevent post content from running up against a floated image.
 *
 * @since 3.7.0
 *
 * @see img_caption_shortcode()
 *
 * @param int    $width    Width of the caption in pixels. To remove this inline style,
 *                         return zero.
 * @param array  $atts     Attributes of the caption shortcode.
 * @param string $content  The image element, possibly wrapped in a hyperlink.
 */
$caption_width = apply_filters( 'img_caption_shortcode_width', $width, $atts, $content );
```

So it looks like this should disable the inline style:

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode_width', '__return_zero' );
```